# Dropdown not showing properly in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

My HTML dropdown is showing properly in all the browsers except safari.
Please provide me some solution.
Code:

```
<select id='drop' style='width:inherit;vertical-align:inherit;'><option value='empty'>Select</option>
<option value='Abc'>Abc</option>
<option value='Xyz'>Xyz</option>
<option value='123'>123</option>
</select>
```

[Dropdown on safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YYot.png)

[Dropdown on other browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjBUi.png)

Comment: A couple of ?s
-- Try including a link to a codepen example -- Displayed images have different content
-- What version of Safari? What OS?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

guess you forgot the **select** end tag

```
    <select id='drop' style='width:inherit;vertical-align:inherit;'>
     <option value='empty'>Select</option>
     <option value='empty'>Abc</option>
     <option value='empty'>Xyz</option>
     <option value='empty'>123</option>
    </select>
```

This should work fine now.

Comment: sorry </select> is also there but i forgot to add it.